# self registration Grails access via http (Android Client)

Tags: android, http, authentication, grails, spring-security

People, I have a system written in grails that makes use of Spring Security Core plugin. Now I made an Android (Java) client to access some data via HTTP. At first my code was being blocked by the spring security when i was using this code below:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider(); credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("LOGIN", "PWD");
httpClient.setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);
```

it was redirecting me to the login page, but then a friend of mine configured the server and the client to use BASIC HTTP authorization, and it worked, the client sent the request, and the response was OK. But now my login page is not working, if the user is not logged in it is showed a default "basic" login/password screen to him, and not my customized login page.

if it is of any help the client code that "works" is below...

```
// HTTP Authentication 

// Type of authentication
List<String> authPrefs = new ArrayList<String>(2);
authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.BASIC);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.auth.scheme-pref", authPrefs);
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(urlHost, urlPort),new UsernamePasswordCredentials("login", "pwd"));

//Preemptive mode

BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
localcontext.setAttribute("preemptive-auth", basicAuth);
httpContext = localcontext;

AbstractHttpMessage method = null;
method = new HttpGet(urlStr);
method.setParams(new BasicHttpParams().setParameter(urlStr, url));

// Now Execute:
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute((HttpUriRequest) method, httpContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you out? This shows how you can use basic auth for some sections of your Grails web-app (where a generic window asks for username and password) and the "regular" login form for others (default web login page).

http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#9.1%20Basic%20and%20Digest%20Authentication